# Reconfigure DNSMasq To Run PHP Sites to Run At A New Specified Location In URL

Tags: php, mysql, macos, phpstorm

Folloring [This Tutorial](https://echo.co/blog/os-x-1010-yosemite-local-development-environment-apache-php-and-mysql-homebrew) I configured my OSX install to run my localhost php sites to be accessable through any url path with the extension .dev

So I have a Sites folder which would be the equivalent of htdocs on my osx install. When I drop a folder in Sites/folder and then op[pen a browser and type in folder.dev the sit runs in the same way as if I were running mamp and I were to type in localhost/myNewWebSite

I am trying to learn `PHPStorm` and my current setup makes configuring phpStorm difficult to setup.

I want to change setup to run websites dropped in the Sites folder at localhost/myNewWebsite instead of with the .dev extension.

In the tutorial this part changed it so I could access localhost with the .dev extension,

```
With DNSMasq running, configure OS X to use your local host for DNS queries ending in .dev:

sudo mkdir -v /etc/resolver 
sudo bash -c 'echo "nameserver 127.0.0.1" > /etc/resolver/dev'
sudo bash -c 'echo "port 35353" >> /etc/resolver/dev'
```

How can I change this to allow me to use localhost instead?

Unless someone can explain to me how to setup phpStorm using my current DNSmasq configuration (with .dev instead of localhost)

Please tell me how to configure it back to just the normal more common localhost.

My other option is to just install MMAP and start from scratch but I am afraid of having all my current setting installe diwth home brew end up conflicting with my new fresh mmamp install.

If you do think intalling MMAMP is the better way to go please tell me what and how to uninstall the current config so I do not haeva ny conflict in my system.

After everything I want to be able to use phpstorm for all my localhost development. Using phpStorm to connect to my server as well as mySQL database locally and on my remote server. Debugging I would like to be done with `Xdebug` which in installed with `brew install php54-xdebug`

But that is as far as I have got. Thank you in advance for any help you may provide!

Comment: Do you have TLDR version of this epic novel? (sorry, but it's too long and chaotic (for me at least) -- I could not figure out the core of your issue). If you want to change URLs then please specify: 1) what you have right now and what you want to have 2) How do you "make" those URLs that you are having right now. P.S. Screenshots are always welcome.

Comment: haha thanks man, but I got it knocked out. I went ahead and uninstalled home brew and set mamp up. Then reinstalled homebrew installed git and configured phpstorm with a mamp setup instead. Thing were just way easier that way. This also fixed other problems I was having that was awesome too!